# i want to save image in sql lite with name and status message and also retrieve it

Tags: android, sqlite, imageview

i want to save image in sql lite with name and status message and also retrieve it.I want to save the image form the imageview which i get from the gallery and also retrieve it image view.I dont know how i save image in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert an image into SQLite database, you need to use BLOB type

See this link :

http://tttrung43.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/store-image-in-sqlite-database/

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/insert-image-to-database/

Answer (score 0):

Convert image to `Base64` String and save in database table with columns such as img_name, status, img
Checkout `Base64` class in android

```
public static String convertImageToBase64(Bitmap img)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, baos);  
        byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray(); 
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

public static Bitmap convertBase64ToImage(String base64)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    }
```

please refer below links for sqlite

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Comment: for this i want to make a row in database?? also i want to retrive it in image view??

Comment: do you know how to create table in sqlite?

Comment: check updated answer and if you got what you want please accept it

Comment: after converting image to base64 string it is the normal operation of inserting and retrieving... after retriving base64 string you have to convert it to bitmap by doing reverse operation.

Comment: Thanx boss for your answer